# How to get base64 envelope for transactions or operations?

Tags: xdr

I am trying to get the resulting base64 output of creating operations and signing transactions but I can't find the method in the transaction object. I know there is transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR() but it gives me bytes, so is there a direct method or do I need to make a manual conversion from bytes to base64?

Answer (score 3):

I already found out, just needed to add 'base64' as a parameter:

```
transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64')
```